# Media3 notification: How to update title dynamically during playback

Tags: android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-mediasession, android-media3, exoplayer-media-item

I need to modify the title shown in the media notification based on the current playback position. According to the documentation, I can use `MediaNotification.Provider` however the document also says this

```
Note: Starting with API 33 the System UI notification is populated from the data in the session.
Accordingly, customizations of the MediaNotification.Provider have effect before API 33 only.
```

For 33 and above, I can update metadata but cannot call `setMediaItem` on the player again as that will disturb the current playback session (plays from the beginning).

Question 1: Using media3 default notification, how do I update title on the fly?

If my only option is build custom notification,

Question 2: How to disable default mediastyle notification? (currently I see two notifications)

Question 3: How to create my own layout and show / update data on that?

Here is the service:

```
class PlaybackService : MediaSessionService() {
    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null
    private lateinit var playerNotificationManager: PlayerNotificationManager
    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(...)
            .build()
            .apply {
                addListener(object : Player.Listener {
                    ...
                })
                playWhenReady = true
            }

        mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, player)
            .build()

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
        createChannel()

        playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setNotificationListener(object : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {
                override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int, dismissedByUser: Boolean) {
                    // Handle notification being dismissed by the user
                }

                override fun onNotificationPosted(notificationId: Int, notification: Notification, ongoing: Boolean) {
                    // Handle notification being posted
                    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
                }
            })
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(object : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
                override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player): CharSequence {
                    return "My Title"
                }

                override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player): PendingIntent? {
                    return null
                }

                override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player): CharSequence {
                    return "My Description"
                }

                override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(player: Player, callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback): Bitmap? {
                    return null
                }
            })
            .build()
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player)
        ///playerNotificationManager.setMediaSessionToken(mediaSession.token) <-- not sure if session token needs to be set
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        mediaSession?.player?.stop()
        stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
        stopSelf()
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaSession?.run {
            player.release()
            release()
            mediaSession = null
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession? {
        return mediaSession
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createChannel() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL,
            this.getString(R.string.playback_notification_channel),
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
        channel.enableLights(false)
        channel.enableVibration(false)
        channel.setShowBadge(false)
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL = "player_channel"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating PlayerNotificationManager, all we need to do is to override this method in MediaNotification.Provider

```
fun getNotificationContentText(MediaMetadata metadata): CharSequence
```

Once the above object is created, from MediaSessionService, need to call

```
setMediaNotificationProvider(provider)
```